# select sum(amount) as total with condition on total

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to get users with total transactions more than 50000

```
SELECT   sum(tractions.amount) as total , user_id  FROM `tractions` where `total` > 50000   group by user_id
```

i get this error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'
```

of curse there is no total column in table but how should i write the condition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `having` clause with aggregation totals:

```
SELECT   sum(tractions.amount) as total , user_id 
FROM `tractions`
group by user_id
HAVING total > 50000;
```

EDIT:

If I were writing this query, it would look like this:

```
select t.user_id,  sum(t.amount) as total
from tractions t
group by t.user_id
having sum(t.amount) > 50000;
```

I find capitalized keywords distracting.  I (almost) always put the fields I am aggregating by at the beginning of a line.  I use table aliases prolifically and they are abbreviations for the table.  I don't escape identifiers, because I never use reserved words or exceptional characters in identifiers.  I put the expression in the `having` clause because . . . well, I think once upon a time, not all databases supported using column aliases in `having` clauses.

Comment: Why you use `tractions.` for `amount` but not for `user_id`?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan . . . Because I left the query as much in the original form as possible.  That is how the OP specified the query.

Comment: Yes I didn't comment to OP because I wanted you to add side-note regarding this in your answer. Additionally `\`` should be used everywhere and all Keywords in Caps-letters.

Comment: Gordon If I use `..as t` then actually I don't need to escape even if a  field name is keyword. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT   sum(tractions.amount) as total , user_id  FROM `tractions` where  sum(tractions.amount) > 50000   group by user_id
```

Comment: i get #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: Sorry you have to use having as you have group by check the one `Gordon` gave

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   sum(tractions.amount) as total , user_id  
FROM `tractions` 
where sum(tractions.amount) > 50000   
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    sum(tractions.amount) as total, user_id
FROM
    `tractions`
group by user_id
having total > 50000;
```